# Create a standalone page to demo a React component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have written a React module and I'm trying to write a standalone test page for demonstration purposes.

I have started with examples from: https://dev.to/jeetvora331/write-react-code-with-cdn-in-html-56i9 and https://github.com/Dereje1/Recipe/blob/master/index.html to produce the following. However I can’t seem to get the correct combination of import/exports to make it all work. I get reference errors, unknown require, undefined name and a host of other import/export related problems.

Web page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>React-ImgBox</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.10.3/babel.min.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script type="text/babel" data-type="module" src="reactjs-imgbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
        const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
        root.render(<Main />);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

`Main.js` demo code:

```
'use client'

import ImgBox from './reactjs-imgbox.js'

function Example1(props) {
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                <div className="panel panel-default">
                    <div className="panel-body">Use x and y co-ordinates with width and height.</div>
                </div>
                <pre id="jack_me_img_code"></pre>
                <pre id="jack_me_js_code"></pre>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
                <ImgBox x="525" y="50" w="300" h="350" name="jack_me" markStyle={{'border': '4px solid red'}}
                    id="jack_me" className="img-fluid"
                    src="//cdn.bigsoft.co.uk/projects/jquery-imgbox/img/jack_me.jpg" />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export function Main(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            <Example1/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

`react-imgbox.js` module to be tested:

```
'use client'

import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react'

    
export default function ImgBox(props) {

    return (
        <div>
            Hello World
        </div>
    )

}
```

How can I glue them together to get what I want?

The `.html` and `main.js` files can be modified for this example but my React module is finished and builds within my (larger) Node project so I don't really want to change it at this late stage if possible.

**Update**

If I put the whole thing together and remove the imports then I can get it to work e.g.

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>

    <script type="text/babel" data-presets="react,stage-3">
    // import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } from 'react'
    const { useCallback, useEffect, useMemo, useRef, useState } = React

        function ImgBox(props) {
          ...
        }

    function Example1(props) {
       return (...)
    }
    function Main(props) {
        // as before
    }


    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
    root.render(<Main />)
</script>
```

Is there no way to make it work with the code spread over different files?

Comment: You need a compiler like webpack, vite, or others...

Comment: @Arkellys - Indeed (It's called a *bundler*, FWIW.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I know, but in the end they still compile the code.

Comment: @Arkellys - They often have bundled compilers (TypeScript compiler/transpiler, minifiers), but the tool is called a *bundler*. The point of the comment is only that that's the term the OP should be searching for in relation to this task.

Comment: Yes, I understand, you're right.

Comment: I have updated the question which shows that I can make it work without any of your suggestions with some minor tweaks (change/remove import statement + remove use client) if I put the whole thing inline. So if I can get it to work inline is there really no way todo this in one page without a tonne of precompiling/transpiling - I thought that is what babel is for!

Comment: You can still use native browser modules and `import` your own `.js` files, without compiling / transpiling. The only thing that doesn't work is trying to `import` something from the `node_modules` folder, since that folder doesn't exist.